# MS Access: Custom report parameterization with tempvars

Tags: ms-access, vba, report

This report image shows a report which should open with tempVars set in place from a couple controls on a form which gets those values and therefore, assigns those to the named vars in the image. Currently, the `WHERE` clause is not working, some parameters do not match or are not getting the variables they should to read and therefore, open a report with the specified information in the `WHERE` condition clause. How might the where condition be modified to get the parameters to work?
(as you can see I erased some information to make is simpler.)
[image]

```
'------------------------------------------------------------
' Expirig_Click
'
'------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub Expirig_Click()
On Error GoTo Expirig_Click_Err


    DoCmd.OpenReport "Expiring", acViewPreview, "", "[DuesExpire]=[TempVars]![tempExpirationDate] And [Type]=[TempVars]![tempType]", acNormal
    TempVars.Add "tempType", Combo164
    TempVars.Add "tempExpirationDate", CutoffDate
    DoCmd.OpenReport "Expiring", acViewReport, "", "[DuesExpire]=[TempVars]![tempExpirationDate] And [Type]=[TempVars]![tempType]", acNormal


Expirig_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub

ExpirigLabels_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Expirig_Click_Exit

End Sub
```

Comment: Hardly anyone uses Access macros, I think. Can you convert this macro to VBA and post the code? It will be much easier to read.

Comment: That option is grayed out for some reason. Is there a way to enable it?

Comment: Got it figured out.... will repost edits.

Comment: Never used it, sorry. But you can create the code yourself: you need `DoCmd.OpenReport "Expiring", ...` and `myVar = [something]` for the elements of your macro.

Comment: Okay. I edited the code.

Comment: I don't use tempvars very often, but from the VBA code you've posted, it looks like your first `DoCmd.OpenReport` line makes use of them, yet they don't appear to be initialised *before* this line (they are initialised *after* this line however). Are they initialised anywhere else before this first `DoCmd.OpenReport` line is executed?

Answer (score 0):

Use VBA variables instead of TempVars, and take them out of the constant WHERE string. Like this:

```
Dim myDate As Date
Dim myType As String

myDate = CutoffDate
myType = Combo164

DoCmd.OpenReport "Expiring", acViewPreview, , _
  "[DuesExpire] = #" & Format(myDate, "mm\/dd\/yyyy") & "# AND [Type] = '" & myType & "'"
```

If Type is not string but number, it's simply `[Type] = " & myType` without the '

Filtering for dates in Access SQL needs a special format: `= #mm/dd/yyyy#`

`Format(myDate, "mm\/dd\/yyyy")` is only needed, if your regional settings have a date format different than mm/dd/yyyy (i.e. if you're not in the US)

Comment: I will try this. My goal is to be able to print this view or export it given the code. How would you use the export portion?

Comment: Interesting. It appears to do what is written in code but the report already has parameters elsewhere which are equivalent. Yet it is not as flexible or user friendly, preferred a form without popups. What should I do about the extra parameters?

Comment: Export to where? Parameters: I don't understand - maybe explain in a new question.

Comment: I get the parameters from the report as if I did not use the form controls. So if you would use the table of contents these would popup as usual because nothing plugs in the data selection. So these parameters which generate the query and report do not appear to be filled in with the code. Am I clear? The export should have an automatic dialogue I just do not know the DoCmd. to activate the method to export (maybe I can find a MS library on that).

Comment: "Am I clear?" - sorry, but (for me) no. :(  As I said, I suggest a new question with all details and more explanation than fits in a comment.